# jquery row and column highlight not working in datatables (rails app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

I have the following code in "listings.js" in my rails app. Im using the gem datatables to show some data. I would like to have my columns and rows highlighted as shown in this [example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/highlight.html). But the highlight feature is not working in my app.

```
//Initialize the datatable
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var listingsTable = $('#listings').dataTable(
  {
    "sPaginationType":  "full_numbers",
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bSortClasses": false,
    "sScrollX": "90%",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "sDom":  '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>',
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": $('#listings').data('source')
  });

  $('td', listingsTable.fnGetNodes()).hover(function() 
    {
        var iCol = $('td').index(this) % 5;
        var nTrs = listingsTable.fnGetNodes();
        $('td:nth-child('+(iCol+1)+')', nTrs).addClass( 'datatablerowhighlight' );
    }, 
    function() 
    {
        $('td.datatablerowhighlight',     listingsTable.fnGetNodes()).removeClass('datatablerowhighlight');
    } );

});
```

Here is my listings.css.scss file

```
.datatablerowhighlight 
{
    background-color: #ECFFB3 !important;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables, try adding:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

to your Gemfile and

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

to app/assets/javascripts/application.js.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response but,I already have added the gem and updated everything according to the railscasts episode. I have my datatable nicely formatted with pagination and search just like in the episode. But, I cannot get the row and column highlight to work as illustrated in the example which has a link above in my post.

Comment: I am seeing that the function oCol is undefined. Are you getting the same error? If so, there seem to be other posts about this issue like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405429/ocol-is-undefined-using-datatables-and-jquery-ui-dialog .

Comment: It's in datatable's javascript. I notice the error coming up when I inspect the loaded javascript in my browser with firebug console.